# Airflow - Sequential runs for Dynamic task mapping

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have a use case where I want to run dynamic tasks.
The expectation is

```
Task1 (output = list of dicts)-> Task2(a) - > Task3(a)
                           |
                           ----> Task 2(b) -> Task3(b)
```

Task 2 and Task 3 needs to be run for every object in list and needs to be sequential.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect multiple dynamically mapped tasks. For example:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

with DAG(dag_id="so_74848271", schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1)):

    @task
    def start():
        return [{"donald": "duck"}, {"bugs": "bunny"}, {"mickey": "mouse"}]

    @task
    def create_name(cartoon):
        first_name = list(cartoon.keys())[0]
        last_name = list(cartoon.values())[0]
        return f"{first_name} {last_name}"

    @task
    def print_name(full_name):
        print(f"Hello {full_name}")

    print_name.expand(full_name=create_name.expand(cartoon=start()))
```

The task `create_name` will generate one task for each dict in the list returned by `start`. And the `print_name` task will generate one task for each result of `create_name`.

The graph view of this DAG looks as follows:

[image]

Comment: But this is not what I want to do. I want to be able to create tasks such that two tasks are completed for one batch component.

Comment: Could you provide an example and a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a list of variable - > [A,B,C,D,E], For all the variables I want to run two tasks. Let say update and update_1. I dont want to run update for the entire list and then update_1 for entire list. I want that for value A, DAG should run update, then update_1, then for B, it should run update and update_1

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you are asking with task decorators in airflow 2.3+ by feeding the output list of dicts into both update and update_1. I modified @Bas Harenslak's answer to show this below:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task

with DAG(dag_id="so_74848271", schedule_interval=None, start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 9, 13)):

    @task
    def start():
        return [{"donald": "duck"}, {"bugs": "bunny"}, {"mickey": "mouse"}]

    @task
    def swap_names(cartoon):
        first_name = list(cartoon.keys())[0]
        last_name = list(cartoon.values())[0]
        return {last_name : first_name}

    @task
    def say_hi(full_name):
        first_name = list(full_name.keys())[0]
        return {"Hello": first_name}

    cartoon = start()    

    out1 = swap_names.expand(cartoon=cartoon)

    out2 = say_hi.expand(full_name=cartoon)

    say_hi.expand(full_name=out1)

    swap_names.expand(cartoon=out2)
```

Then the DAG will look like what you've drawn in your question (sorry I don't have enough reputation to embed the image): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNQp.png

References: https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamic-tasks#repeated-mapping